# Counting $_POST

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, count

I have a big form that contains X amount of posts that has 15 fields per post along with 1 hidden field.

Let's assume I have 14 posts. This means my form would send 211 fields (14x15 fields plus 1 hidden field).

The user does not have to fill in all fields.

I want to count the number of posts that the form sends but I seem to be running into difficulty.

Using count($_POST) returns 152. This leads me to believe that count() is ignoring empty fields.

As a result, using a formula such as (count($_POST) - 1) / 15 would return the wrong result (10.0666) and is inefficient should the number of fields change in the future.

So, does anyone have any ideas as to how to get the proper count of my posts?

My form looks like so:

```
<form name="scraped" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="OSscraper_hidden" value="N">
        <?php
            $inpCnt = 0;
            foreach($articles as $item) {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="title_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="name_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="url_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="img_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="pet_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="color_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="value_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="height_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="weight_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="hair_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="eyes_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="race_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="phone_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="address_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="zip_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>">
        <?php 
            $inpCnt++;
        } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: It might be suprise for you but you can pass array thru POST as it gonna be ideal solution for you. And `action=""` attribute is not necessary if you want to send data to same page. [EXAMPLE](https://gist.github.com/4650062). And your POST count will be `count($_POST['article']) * count($attrs)`;

Comment: count() doesnt ignore anything. as a programmer, you must use some basic debugging to accomplish your tasks. maybe `print_r($_POST);` or `var_dump($_POST);` can help you get started.

Comment: You could add a hidden field with the number of posts.

Comment: @rambo coder I'm not an idiot. I've used var dump and it shows me everything. I can guarantee you that count is in fact ignoring all the fields that are empty. There are 211 fields and count returns 152 since there are 59 empty fields.

Comment: @Sweepster dont get upset. if you dont show people how you've debugged, it would be illogical to assume you have. You should post the output of `echo base64_encode(serialize($_POST));` and prove it to us.

Comment: I'm not upset. Sorry if it sounded like it.

Comment: @rambocoder why he needs to `serialize` and `base64_encode` to show this? `var_export` is enough for this.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im var_export is fine, but base64 is always a good idea to provide a binary safe transport to us. not that i think its an issue here, but its a matter of thoroughness.

Comment: @Sweepster are you aware that theres 152 entries in there? count is working fine. Your problem is elsewhere. look at `max_input_vars` config variable, and verify the html source code in the form.

Comment: @rambocoder you're right. I've discovered the reason: some fields contained the same name. I'm working on fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form to look like:

```
<input type="text" name="foo[<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>][title]">
<input type="text" name="foo[<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>][name]">
<input type="text" name="foo[<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>][url]">
```

Then you will get:

```
$_POST['foo'] = [
  0 => ['title' => '...', 'name' => '...', 'url' => '...'],
  1 => ...,
  ...
];
```

It saves you from having to do the grouping yourself, and is easier to count or iterate over the input.

Comment: This helped me find a solution by implementing the above, count($_POST['foo']) gave me the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why not just `count($articles)*15` and echo into a hidden input. You are using another hidden input anyway....

Comment: Because 15 isn't a fixed number. If the admin wants to add fields, I'd have to change the variable manually.

Comment: Could you just set a default value to the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, and demo is [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/udz-2vr)
Please just use the idea not the exact copy.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
//debugging

if(@$_POST['submit'] == 'Submit'){
 echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
 echo '</pre>';
 echo "<br>\n";
 echo 'Number of posts = count($_POST["posts"])='.count(@$_POST['posts'])."<br>\n";

 //finding number of posts that are set and not empty
 $count = 0;
 foreach($_POST['posts'] as $v1){
  //$v is an array
  foreach($v1 as $v1k=> $v1v){
   if(strlen($v1v) > 0){
    ++$count;
    $inputs[$v1k] = $v1v;
   }
  }
 }


 echo 'Count of non-empty posts = $count = '.$count."<br>\n";
 echo '<pre>';
    print_r($inputs);
 echo '</pre>';
}
?>
<form name="scraped" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="OSscraper_hidden" value="N">
        <?php
            $articles =array('test');
            $inpCnt = 0;
            foreach($articles as $item) {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="posts[][title_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][name_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][url_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][img_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][pet_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][color_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][value_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][height_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][weight_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][hair_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][eyes_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][race_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][phone_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][address_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <input type="text" name="posts[][zip_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>]">
        <?php 
            $inpCnt++;
        } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: That code is completely unnecessary. Simply echoing count($_POST[posts]) does the trick.